# This is someone else's code. I am trying to get it to work but dont know whats wrong.

Tags: syntax

Can someone please help me get rid of this error?

Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'INTO'.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 24
Incorrect syntax near 'LocationID'.

```
use DB1

-- Declare variables
declare @AnalysisSID varchar(10)
declare @ExposureDB varchar(250)
declare @AnalysisName varchar(250)

-- !! begin user input !! -------------------------------------------------------------------
set @AnalysisSID =9
set @ExposureDB = (select ExposureDataSourceName
                  from t9_LOSS_DimExposureDataSource) --<--!!! update result table number

-- !! end user input !! ----------------------------------------------------------------------
set @AnalysisName = (select AnalysisName from tAnalysisResult where ResultSID = @AnalysisSID)

Exec(
'
if not (exists (select * from sysobjects where name = ''LOSSES_FORFEED''))
begin
CREATE TABLE LOSSES_FORFEED (
Name varchar(250) NOT NULL,
LOCID varchar(100) NOT NULL,
ContractID varchar(100) NOT NULL,
GroundUp_Loss float,
Gross_Loss float)
end

INTO LOSSES_FORFEED
SELECT  
'''+@AnalysisSID+''' as AnalysisID, '''+@AnalysisName+''' as Name,
l.LocationID as LOCID,
c.ContractID,
sum(GroundUpLoss) as GroundUp_Loss, 
sum(GrossLoss) as Gross_Loss
FROM t'+@AnalysisSID+'_LOSS_ByLocationSummary loss
join '+@ExposureDB+'..tLocation l on loss.LocationSID = l.LocationSID
join '+@ExposureDB+'..tContract c on l.ContractSID = c.ContractSID
group by 
c.ContractID,
l.LocationID
')
```

Comment: What database is that?

Comment: Also, exactly which line are you getting the error on?

Comment: I changed the DB name. also when I double click the first error it takes me to this line       from t9_LOSS_DimExposureDataSource) --<--!!! update result table number

Comment: No.  What RDBMS are you using?  Also, please tag your question SQL.

Comment: MS SQl Server Database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to add an `INSERT` before `INTO LOSSES_FORFEED`:

```
INSERT INTO LOSSES_FORFEED
```

That should work - at least for an MS SQl Server Database. But also the amount of arguments don't match: the table `LOSSES_FORFEED` has 5 columns but in the select statement you're providing 6 arguments.

Comment: I did. Its gives me this error instead: Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 12
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

Comment: Thank you that worked!!! I removed '''+@AnalysisSID+''' as AnalysisID, from the insert into section and added Insert before 'Into'. Thanks!!!!